# Material doesn't cover extruded circle?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, extrude

I made a triangle by creating a circle and then reducing the vertices to 3. Then i changed to positions of the corner points using edit mode. After that i extruded the triangle to be, what I assume to be called, a mesh. But now, as you can see in the screenshots, if I want to apply a material, only the extruded edges get covered with it, not the triangular surface itself. I tried UV Mapping it, but that didn't change anything. I'm fairly new to Blender, so I don't know a fix.

What can I do about this?

Screenshots:
[image: Overview]

[image: Close Up]

[image: UV Map]

Comment: Hello, your screenshots didn't make it into the question.  You can [edit] the question to add them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a *Mesh Circle* is instantiated, it is only the vertices and edges - it doesn't have an inner face yet.

First, starting with a 3 vert circle, you can select all the vertices and create a new face with <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image]

Then, when you extrude <kbd>E</kbd> up, a new face will be created on top as well, and you're left with a fully manifold shape.

[image]

You can then generate UVs or otherwise apply a material as normal.

Comment: Thank you, that was the fix!